# Which is a good value for COCO mAP?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

in the Google Object Detection API there are pre-trained models and for each one is indicated the COCO mAP. I know what is COCO mAP and how it is calculated. The question is...what is a good value for COCO mAP?

Answer (score 1):

You can look in a few model zoos or benchmarks. For example:

- [TF OD API mode zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md#coco-trained-models)
- [MS COCO detection leaderboards](https://cocodataset.org/#detection-leaderboard)
- [Papers with Code - COCO detection task](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/object-detection-on-coco)

You will be able to see that a SOTA mAP is 55+.